# Confused by Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I feel confused by the Dockerfile and build process. Specifically, I am working my way through the book [Docker on AWS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1788626508) and I feel stuck until I can work my way through a few more of the details. The book had me write the following Dockerfile.

```
#Test stage
FROM alpine as test
LABEL application=todobackend

#Install basic utilities
RUN apk add --no-cache bash git

#Install build dependencies
RUN apk add --no-cache gcc python3-dev libffi-dev musl-dev linux-headers mariadb-dev py3-pip
RUN ../../usr/bin/pip3 install wheel

#Copy requirements
COPY /src/requirements* /build/
WORKDIR /build

#Build and install requirements
RUN pip3 wheel -r requirements_test.txt --no-cache-dir --no-input
RUN pip3 install -r requirements_test.txt -f /build --no-index --no-cache-dir

# Copy source code
COPY /src /app
WORKDIR /app

# Test entrypoint
CMD ["python3","manage.py","test","--noinput","--settings=todobackend.settings_test"]
```

The following is a list of the things I understand versus don't understand.

1. I understand this.

```
    #Test stage
    FROM alpine as test
    LABEL application=todobackend
```

It is defining a 'test' stage so I can run commands like `docker build --target test` and will execute all of the following commands until the next FROM / as command indicates a different target. LABEL is labeling the specific docker image that is built and from which containers will be 'born' (not sure if that is the right word to use). I don't feel any confusion about that EXCEPT if that tag translates to containers spawned from that image.

So NOW I start to feel confused.

2. I PARTLY understand this

```
    #Install basic utilities
    RUN apk add --no-cache bash git
```

I understand that apk is an overloaded term that represents both the package manager on Alpine Linux and a file type. In this context, it is a package manager command to install (or upgrade) a package to the running system. HOWEVER, I am suppose to be building / packaging up an application and all of its dependencies into an enclosed 'environment'. Sooo... where / when does this 'environment' come in? That is where I feel confused. When the docker file is running apk, is it just saying "locally, on your current machine, please install these the normal way." (ie, the equivalent of a bash script where apk installs to its working directory). When I run `docker build --target test -t todobackend-test` on my previously pasted docker file, is the `docker` command doing both a native command execution AND a Docker Engine call to create an isolated environment for my docker image? I `feel` like what must be happening is when the `docker` command is run it acts like a wrapper around the built-in package manager / bash / pip functionality AND the docker engine and is doing both but I don't know.

Anyways, I feel hope that this made sense. I just want some implementation details. Feel free to link documentation but it can feel super tedious and unnecessarily detailed OR obfuscated sometimes.

I DO want to point out that if I run an apk command in my Dockerfile with a bad dependency name (e.g. `python3-pip` instead of `py3-pip`). I get a very interesting error:

`/bin/sh: pip3: not found`
Notice the command path. I am assuming anyone reading this will understand why that feels hella confusing.

Comment: By `RUN apk add...` you are installing software in the Docker image that you are building.

Comment: _"When I run `docker build` on my previously pasted docker file, is the docker command doing both a native command execution AND a Docker Engine call to create an isolated environment for my docker image?"_ - no, only the latter. The commands you `RUN` are executed in that isolated environment (Alpine Linux in your case, which should explain your confusion with `/bin/sh` too)

Comment: If you really want lots of gory details about internals, google about "linux mount namespaces" and "pivot_root" or even just "chroot". In short - the commands in the Dockerfile are executed within a subtree of your filesystem, which usually represents a root filesystem of some distribution (e.g. Alpine). The features named above ensure that containerized processes see this subtree as a full OS' filesystem. Thus, executables called in Dockerfile (like `apk`) are searched within this tree, and a package managers like `apk` install packages to this tree, not to the host's `/`.

Comment: Wow. These were amazing answers and super fast. Answered my questions and makes sense. Thanks.